# Using Alasql in AngularJS Factory

Tags: angularjs, alasql

So I am making an AngularJS project and want to put my alasql functionality within a factory that I will inject into my controllers.  However, I am getting a console error stating that alasql is not defined in my factory.  Here is my code for some files:

```
// sqlFactory.js

angular.module('app').factory('sqlFactory', sqlFactory);
function sqlFactory() {
    alasql("CREATE localStorage DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db");
    alaqsl("ATTACH localStorage DATABASE db");
    alaqsl("USE db");
    .......
}
```

I think I am handling the injection into the controller correctly:

```
// myController.js

angular.module("app").controller("myController", myController);
myController.$inject = ['sqlFactory'];

function myController(sqlFactory) {
    ....
}
```

And I am referencing the alasql file in my layout page, although maybe not in the correct order? :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alasql/0.4.3/alasql-worker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/sqlFactory.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/site.js"></script>
```

I am fairly new to using factories and alasql.  Anyone know why it is coming back as undefined?  Do I need to inject alasql into my factory?

Comment: I solved it, I mistyped alasql as alaqsl.  Changed it & everything works, don't need to inject alasql itself as a dependency.